# How to tell age of Sandisk SSD

Tags: hard-drive

Hello I bought an sandisk ssd from Amazon and it is much slower than the exact same drive I also bought from sandisk. I am wondering if there is any way to check the age and usage of an SSD to see if I got a used one. I am new to Ubuntu from windows so please explain as if I am a 5 year old. Thanks

Comment: Are you using a different filesystem ?

Comment: I do not know. I installed the basic ubuntu 16.04 on both and one seemed slower. Should  I try a different file system to speed this one up?

Comment: No. Gparted is in the Live session but you can install it with apt-get

Comment: sudo _apt-get install apatitude_ and _aptitude search gparted_ to see the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run `sudo apt install smartmontools`
2. Run `sudo fdisk -l` to output a list of  drives on the system. For example, on my system my primary drive shows as /dev/nvme0n1.
3. Verify this with `mount | grep 'on / type'`. The output will show the same drive location with a partition number attached to it. For example, on my system it is /dev/nvme0n1p3.
4. Run `sudo smartctl --xall /dev/yourdevice` (without the p#).

Comment: `smartctl` is not installed by default, not likely OP has it.

Comment: Oops, I've edited my answer to include smartmontools package.

Comment: sorry i'm a little confused on mount grep | 'on / type' what should i type for the 'on / type' part? thanks for the help Andrew

Comment: The | key is Shift + \, and the ' key is a single quote, probably next to your Enter key. You can also copy and paste that string into your terminal. Use Ctrl + Shift + V to paste into your terminal. What that string does is search your mountpoints for the root mount, which would be your primary drive in question.

Comment: I dont know what `mount grep | 'on / type'` aims to do, but doesn't work for me either.

Comment: I just fixed the string, I had the | in the wrong place.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` shows `/dev/sda` and `mount | grep 'on / type'` shows `/dev/sda2` :/

Comment: That's good, we can ignore the # at the end. Your system is using the "older" method displaying partition numbers, which are just a number appended to the end of the device name. So now that you've verified it is /dev/sda, you can run the last command "sudo smartctl --xall /dev/sda"

Comment: ok the information shows up but what numbers do I look at to figure out if my drive is used?

Comment: You should see multiple lines of data, one of them "Power-on Hours" near the top.

Comment: 23  ---  Power-on Hours So if the drive is new and the same exact model why would this one be slower? Also thanks Andrew and everybody else for helping

Comment: Maybe it's a SATA connection issue with your motherboard? Is it possibly connected to a slower SATA connection (for example my motherboard has both SATA2 and SATA3)?

Comment: Don't forget to please mark my answer as correct if you are satisfied with your initial request.

Answer (score 2):

Going with the `smartmon` tools, you can look at the `Power_On_Hours` to give you an idea of how long the drive could have been booted up.

In a terminal window after installing the `smartmontools`

```
sudo apt install smartmontools
```

run the following command to get the power on hours of all the drives in the host:

```
ls /dev/sd[a-z] | while read drv; do echo -n "$drv "; sudo smartctl -a $drv | grep Power_On_Hours | awk '{print $NF}'; done
```

Break down of the command:

**ls /dev/sd[a-z]** - list all drives /dev/sd? A-Z

**while read drv** - set a variable called $drv for each drive found

**do echo -n "$drv "; sudo smartctl -a $drv** - Start the loop for each found drive.  Get all parameters of all drives found.

**grep Power_On_Hours** - Return the Power On Hours found on the drive

**awk '{print $NF}'** - Return only the last field as this is what we are looking for.

**done:**  Complete the loop.

It is not 100% accurate, but will give you an idea of how long the drive could have been in another computer powered on and possibly in use for.

See my example below:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ls /dev/sd[a-z] | while read drv; do echo -n "$drv "; sudo smartctl -a $drv | grep Power_On_Hours | awk '{print $NF}'; done
/dev/sda /dev/sdb 82578
/dev/sdc 71124
/dev/sdd 32215
/dev/sde 478
/dev/sdf 28062
/dev/sdg 6698
/dev/sdh 1939
```

On my list there, my `/dev/sda` actually does not support `smart` as it is an external usb drive, so it is not listed for the hours, but the rest are.  Yes, my `sdb` drive has been powered on for over 9 years.  It is a WD 250GB SATA drive.

Hope this helps give you an idea of how long the drive may have been used for.

Comment: lenny@lenny-LX6810-01:~$ ls /dev/sd[a-z] | while read drv; do echo -n "$drv "; sudo smartctl -a $drv | grep Power_On_Hours | awk '{print $NF}'; done
/dev/sda [sudo] password for lenny: 
23
/dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf lenny@lenny-LX6810-01:~$ 
So does this mean the ssd has only been on 23 hours?

Comment: @Lenny Are these all external USB drives you have?  Smartmon only is capable of reading internal drives.  Your output is not showing any hours.

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting but it says 23 also it is an internal hard drive and thanks for the help Terrance

Answer (score 1):

You can get a detailed information about any hard disk in your computer with `hdparm`:

```
sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       LITEON CV3-DE256                        
    Serial Number:      ABCDEFGHIJK12345 <====
    Firmware Revision:  TD86201 
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0

...
...
```

From there you can extract the **Serial Number**, and check on the manufacturer's or vendor's website. [Sand Disk's Support website](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/utils/login_form/redirect/account%252Fprodreg%252Falist), you will have to log in/sign up to check information given a Serial Number.

---

As you wanted 5-years-old like explanation:

**1.** Open a terminal:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

  or
- Open Dash (<kbd>Super</kbd>, the windows button right to <kbd>Alt</kbd>) and type *terminal*, now open it.

**2.** Find out the name of your hard disk with `sudo fdisk -l`, shoudl be whatever comes after **Disk /dev/SOMETHING**. You will be asked for your password, type it, and note that it won't show up in the screen, for security reasons.

**3.** Copy and paste `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda` and subsitute `/dev/sda` with your hard disk name.

Answer (score 0):

I got some parentheses in my Power_on_hours results so I had to modify Terrance's command to take them out. Here is what worked for me:

```
ls /dev/sd[a-z] | while read drv; do echo -n "$drv "; sudo smartctl -a $drv | grep Power_On_Hours | sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" | tr -d '(*)' | awk '{print $NF}'; done
```

And here is what gives me the number of days a drive has been on:

```
ls /dev/sd[a-z] | while read drv; do echo -n "$drv "; sudo smartctl -a $drv | grep Power_On_Hours | sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" | tr -d '(*)' | awk '{print $NF/24}'; done
```